# JPA one-many gives null value after mapping

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, mapping, one-to-many

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong (followup on earlier question)?

I have three classes: Dashboard, DashboardUser and User.

Dashboard works fine, with the following code:

```
 @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="dashboard")
    private List<DashboardUser> dashboardUsers = new ArrayList<>();
```

DashboardUser contains the following two JPA declarations:

```
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDUser")
    private User user;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDDashboard")
    private Dashboard dashboard;
```

The problem lies with User.java:

```
@OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="user")
    private List<DashboardUser> dashboardUsers;
```

It looks the same, but only the Dashboard class works as it should.
After executing my code, my dashboard has a dashboardUser among his attributes, the user however has a null value for dashboardUser.

The table in the database has two fields: IDUser and IDDashboard (I do use the right userID and dashboardID). Does someone see my mistake?

Comment: Include the complete mappings, the SQL generated, and the error you are getting.

Comment: Are you serializing the data, any LAZY field will be null when serialized.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `@JoinColumn` annotation to `User`

```
@OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="user")
@JoinColumn(name="dashBoardUserId") //Replace with actual column name
private List<DashboardUser> dashboardUsers;
```

I had to guess the name of the primary key in `DashboardUser` so it will need replaced within the actual code.

After taking a further look at the code, I assumed that `DashboardUser` is a junction table between `Dashboard` and `User` which maps what dashboards a user has access.  This scenario is best mapped by a `@ManyToMany` relationship.  One user may have access to many dashboards, while a dashboard may have many users, hence a many to many relationship.  The following mapping would create a many to many relationship between user and dashboard.

**User.java**

```
public class User{

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity=Dashboard.class)
        @JoinTable(name="DASHBOARD_USER", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="IDUser", referencedColumnName="IDUser")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="IDDashboard",       
        referencedColumnName="IDDashboard")})
     public List<Dashboard> dashboards = new ArrayList<Dashboard>();

     //Other fields/Getters/Setters 
}
```

**Dashboard.java**

```
@Entity
public class Dashboard{

     @ManyToMany(mappedBy="dashboards")
     private List<Users> users;

     //Other fields/Getters/Setters

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. The primary key is a combination of IDUSer and IDDashboard. At the moment, there is no seperate PK id field. Is there a way to use such a composite ID with the joincolumn you gave?